# How to get date input from table created using for loop in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

So I have passed a context from views.py to my html template.

I have created a html table using 'For Loop' in the following way and also added a column with input date field.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead style="background-color:DodgerBlue;color:White;">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Barcode</th>
      <th scope="col">Owner</th>
      <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
      <th scope="col">Address</th>
      <th scope="col">Asset Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Schhedule Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Approve Asset Request</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for i in deliverylist %}
    <tr>
      <td class="barcode">{{i.barcode}}</td>
      <td class="owner">{{i.owner}}</td>
      <td class="mobile">{{i.mobile}}</td>
      <td class="address">{{i.address}}</td>
      <td class="atype">{{i.atype}}</td>
      <td class="deliverydate"><input type="date"></td>
      <td><button id="schedulebutton" onclick="schedule({{forloop.counter0}})" style="background-color:#288233; color:white;" class="btn btn-indigo btn-sm m-0">Schedule Date</button></td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

Now I would like to get that date element value in javascript, but its proving difficult since I am assigning a class instead of id(as multiple elements cant have same id).

I tried in the following way but its not working. The console log shows no value in that variable.

```
<script>                     //i is the iteration number passed in function call using forloop.counter0
    function schedule(i){
        var deldate = document.getElementsByClassName("deliverydate");
        deldate2 = deldate[i].innerText;
        console.log(deldate2);              //log shows no value/empty
        console.log(i);                     //log shows iteration number
</script>
```

Comment: You can assign a unique id to the `input` (e.g. `id="mydate-{{forloop.counter0}}"`) then use something like `.getElementById("mydate-" + i)`.

Comment: @Selcuk its still showing empty value. When I use `.getElementById("mydate-" + i).value` then it shows undefined error.